# VoIP c++ references

Tags: c++, voip

I'm having troubles with finding tutorials/examples of how a simple VoIP application would look like. I've searched the web and found an out-dated step-by-step tutorial, so it wasn't much of a help and that's about it considering tutorials. However I've managed to find some nice API's like libosip ( oSIP ). It would be a great thing if anyone would know any good tutorial; or if anything a small VoIP open source app that i could checkout. I don't really have any troubles with understanding someone else's code if it wasn't commented/explained.

Comment: +1 for "Peace be with you" , I really needed it :)

Comment: SIP is just the session management protocol. You still need a separate audio streaming protocol.

Comment: You can read my answers in another question: [VoIP Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43970929/7877309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great sip framework called [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/). look at [this example](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm) for a short, but yet complete demo. Also take a look in the [PJSUA API](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB.htm).

Comment: Peace be with you,
I'm very grateful for this respond it helped me a lot. Though i had some difficulties compiling the code but I fixed them.
Farewell, Red.